# Why I am getting a garbage value after entering number of test cases in the first line of the input?

Tags: c++, debugging, garbage

***Input:***

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of 
test cases.

The only line of each test case contains the space separated parts of the 
name.

***Output***

For each case, output the properly formatted name.

***Constraints:***

- 1 ≤ T ≤ 100
- 2 ≤ Length of each part of the name ≤ 10
  Each part of the name contains the letters from lower and upper case English 
  alphabets (i.e. from 'a' to 'z', or 'A' to 'Z')

  ```
  ***Input***
  3
  gandhi
  mahatama gandhi
  mohandas karamchand gandhi


  ***Expected Output:***
  Gandhi
  M.Gandhi
  M.K.Gandhi


  ***My output:***
  à
  Gandhi
  M.Gandhi
  M.K.Gandhi
  ```

Why am I getting the "à" symbol in the first line? 
I have created a function formatter to provide a for loop for the testcases.

I apologize in advance if the code is too clunky.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int z;
void formatter(int z){
  for(int q = 0;q <= z;q++){
  string s;
  int count=0;
  int k = 0,p = 0,r = 0,t = 0,l = 0,a = 0,x = 0 ;
  getline(cin,s);
  for(int p = 0;p <= s.size();p++){
    if((s[p]==' ')||(p==0)){
       count++;
       }
  }
  if(count == 1){
    while(r<=s.size()){
    s[0] = s[0] -'a' + 'A';
        cout << s[r] ;
    r++;
  }
   cout << "\n";
  }
  if(count == 2){
    for(int l = 0;l<s.size();l++){
          if(l==0){
             s[l] = s[l] -'a' + 'A';
             cout << s[l] << ".";
             a++;
          }
          if(s[l]==' '){
          if(a==1){
            ++l;
            while(l <= s.size()){
            if(x == 0){
            s[l] = s[l] -'a' + 'A';
          }
            cout << s[l] ;
            a++;
            l++;
            x++;
          }
    }
  }
 }
            cout << "\n";
}
  if(count==3){
  for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
        if(i==0){
                s[i] = s[i] -'a' + 'A';
        cout << s[i] << ".";
        t++;
        }
    if(s[i]==' '){
    if(t==1){
        ++i;
        s[i] = s[i] -'a' + 'A';
        cout << s[i] << ".";
        t++;
    }
    else
    while(k<=10){
    if(k==1){
    s[i] = s[i] -'a' + 'A';
    }
        cout << s[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    }


  }
}


}
 cout << "\n";
}
int main(){
  cin >> z;
  formatter(z);
 }
```

Comment: It's because you don't know how to use a debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, and examining the values of all variables at each step, to see how your code's logic works, and is different from your expected results. And you also are mixing `>>` with `std::getline`, which [doesn't work as you expect it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction), which triggers all the bugs in your code. Use your debugger.

Comment: I can't do that as I need to read the spaces in the string input and cin won't do that...so used getline

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative?@SamVarshavchik

Comment: Yes, use only `std::getline`, to read each line of input. That's what's it's there for. To read a line of text. That's not what `>>` does. Using `>>` and expecting it to read a line of text is not going to work. But without knowing how to use a debugger you'll still have bugs. And there are no alternatives to that. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: I know how to use a debugger.The issue was the debugger couldn't point out why i was getting "a" in the first line of output.It was just moving through the loop without problems.Anyways thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things

- The cin that reads the count in main does not consume the endline
- The loop in formatter is from 0 to the number read in main, inclusive. This is wrong.
- Consider toupper to convert to uppper case.
- Consider factorizing the code that handles 1, 2 and 3 names.